# PSO Package in R always end with an error in while TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, optimization, particle-swarm

Trying to perform ANN optimization but I always get the same error which I cannot resolve.
I put some `trackback()` in my code but nothing was returned except the error below:

```
Error in while (stats.iter < p.maxit && stats.feval < p.maxf && error >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Do you have already seen this error and where i can coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that a condition was to be tested, but it evaluated to `NA`. In optimisation problems, this often happens when your objective function evaluates to `NA` for some parameter values.  (But without a reproducible example, it is hard to tell what exactly went wrong.)

Comment: Thx for your reply. My fitness function is evaluated like that: `fitness <- training_result$metric_val_accuracy`. Maybe I should post the entire code